# Using a class in a VB.net project

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.net (but a long time user of VB 6).  I am trying to use a class in a VB.net project that is in a .dll on my machine.

The developer told me "Look for the WelcomeScreen class to open a channel bar".  I added the .DLL to the Toolbox and went to the Object Viewer and can see the WelcomeScreen class.  My question is how do I call this class in my VB.net project?  In VB 6.0, I was very familiar with constructs such as:

```
Private Declare Function RegQueryValueEx Lib "advapi32.dll" _
Alias "RegQueryValueExA" ( _
ByVal hKey As Long, _
ByVal lpszValueName As String, _
ByVal lpdwReserved As Long, _
lpdwType As Long, _
lpData As Any, _
lpcbData As Long) _
As Long
```

But I'm not sure how to call this WelcomeScreen class.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is it a control? did you add a reference to the assembly in your project?
After adding the refrence you could type the name (WelcomeScreen ) in a .vb file and put the cursor at this word and hit Shift+Alt+F10

Comment: Yes, I think it is a control.  The WelcomeScreen is a dialog box that gets opened in the application.  How do I add a reference to the assembly in my project?  And once I've done that, how would I call the class?  Thx.

Comment: Can you drag & drop the control from the toolbox onto your surface i.e. Windows Form ... don't know what technology u use.

Comment: I don't think I should have added the .dll to the Toolbox.  I did this, but I don't see the control in the Toolbox.  I think I need to do this all with with code.  I am using VB.net. with Visual Studio 2013.  I can see the Class with the Object Browser.  Now I need to figure out how to reference it.

Comment: Go to your toolbox-> right click--> choose items and then pick your dll.
Are u developing Windows Forms or ..?
If it does not appear something is wrong apparently :-)

Comment: Yes, I did this.  When I load TIProGUI.dll, it places a "control" named "AlertFormWrapper" in the list of .NET Framework Components.  If I add this to my form, how can I call the WelcomeScreen class which is in this .dll?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75034/discussion-between-legends-and-user3229570).