# how to show a form from a c# dll in a vb.net appliaction

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am writing a VB.net application and have included a c# dll.  The c# dll has a class called WelcomeScreen.  This class has a form (I saw this in the Object Browser).  How can I show this form in my VB.net application?

This is the code I have so far:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim welcome As New WelcomeScreen(1)
welcome.Show()
```

Comment: Have you tried anything and are getting an error? It is no different from accessing VB classes.

Comment: The only thing I have done is put in the line "Dim c As New WelcomeScreen(1)".  But I don't know what to do to show the form.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried c.Show()?

Comment: Duplicate of [Using a class in a VB.net project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583282/using-a-class-in-a-vb-net-project). Why are you reposting this? If you didn't get a satisfactory answer then edit your original question.

Comment: I just tried that and tried to build.  I got  "Declaration expected" for line 7.  There was also a big warning message "There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built 'MSIL' and the processor architecture of the reference 'TIProGUI', 'x86'

Comment: Please paste the code in and around line 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is no different from showing a form in VB.

```
Dim welcomeScreen as New WelcomeScreen()
welcomeScreen.Show()
```

For basic information of forms in VB.NET you can read this post http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/opening-closing-and-hiding-forms-with-visual-basic.html

It is a nice starting point for basics in VB forms.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that and got the error message above.

Comment: I assume you are writing show with a capital "S" and ending it with brackets as in "welcome.Show()"

Comment: Thanks.  I just changed it to " welcome.Show()" and still get the same error.  Grrr.

Comment: For the warning that you receive, refer to this answer and let me know if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113532/how-do-i-fix-the-visual-studio-compile-error-mismatch-between-processor-archit Though it is for a C++ and a C# project, the same steps should help you.

Comment: Thanks.  I followed the steps and the warning went away.  But I still have the error saying "Declaration expected".  What does this mean?

Comment: Why are you passing a 1 in your constructor?

Comment: @user3229570 You need to put the `.Show` code in a sub or function somewhere, and not in class declaration part. E.g. `Public Class Form1 : Public Sub New() : Me.InitializeComponent() : Dim welcomeScreen as New WelcomeScreen() : welcomscreen.Show() : End Sub : End Class`

Comment: Thanks!  I did this and it compiles just fine.  The problem is I don't know how to call the sub-routine inside Module1.  I tried Module1.Show_it() but it gave me the same error "Declaration expected".

Comment: I added a button to the form that calls Show_it() in the module and it works great.  Thank you.